# React Props do not update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set the state of a nested component from the props of its parent, if I set the checked prop of the Switch directly using the incoming prop of the parent `checked={Boolean(this.props.contData.statesValue.active)}` then the switch ui successfully changes from on to off,

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

class Test extends Component {
            
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Switch checked={Boolean(this.props.contData.statesValue.active)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
}
 
export default (Test);
```

However if I try and set checked via state then the ui is not updated and logging the this.state.checked does not change in value ,

I am hazarding a guess that I am updating the code in  the wrong part of the lifecycle, but any help would be much appreciated

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

class Test extends Component {
        
    state = {
      checked:this.props.contData.statesValue.active
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Switch checked={Boolean(this.state.checked)} />
            </div>
        );
     }
}
 
export default (Test);
```

Answer (score 1):

The state is initially set to prop value and isn't updated when new prop values are received.

This is what `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method is for:

```
state = {};

static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  return {
   checked: !!props.contData.statesValue.active
  };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Switch checked={this.state.checked} />
        </div>
    );
 }
```

A state isn't needed if it doesn't differ from props; a component can be stateless and use props directly instead.

Answer (score 1):

`{Boolean(this.state.checked)}` converts the variable into a boolean which is not a variable anymore. It gets the value of this.state.checked, converts it into a boolean and does not update it anymore since it is not a variable. So you need to modify that to `<Switch checked={this.state.checked} />` instead.